# how do I set shortcuts on sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to be able to make `<%= %>` by pressing '=' and 'tab' like in Atom. I downloaded ERB snippets package but it uses other keys in order to make that shortcut. How do I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime isn't so simple as in Atom, they don't store in the same file, but in a folder within your `User` configuration as different files, to do it just go to `Tools->Developer->New Snippet`, and you'll see a new tab:

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
  <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
  <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
  <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
  <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

All that's between the `CDATA` is the body of your snippet, and is what you'll see on the editor and where you'll define the pointer position, the code block, and a "placeholder" message, try this way:

```
<%= ${1:your_awesome_code} %>
```

Those are the common `erb` markers, and what's inside is what you'll see when you press `tab` or select the snippet, the `${}` is to open and close the statement, the `1` inside is a `field` and is telling that it'll be the first thing you'll have under the cursor, because you can assign this same way one or more `fields` with or without "placeholders", as you want, the `:` will divide it from "order" and "what you'll get", this way, when you use it you'll have:

```
<%= your_awesome_code %>
```

The whole phrase on the cursor, then you can easily erase it and keep coding (it was just an example)

Then within the `<tabTrigger>` tag you declare the shortcut to select the snippet, in this case will be the `=` character, so:

```
<tabTrigger>=</tabTrigger>
```

Now when you type `=` on Sublime and hit the `tab` key the code you defined as snippet will appear on your editor, if it's the only one setted with `=`, if there are two or more you'll have the opportunity to choose between any of them.

And additional you can set the `scope` that's to say, that snippet will only appear in files that are recognized by Sublime as the file extension of that language.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cheat sheet https://www.cheatography.com/tdeyle/cheat-sheets/sublime-text-3/. Hopefully, this helps. I love Sublime, but it takes some time to learn how to use the keystrokes.

If they keystrokes aren't working at all, perhaps try to restart Sublime. Also the free version may have more limits than the purchased one just as a note.